# É errado misturar struct com class em C++?

Tags: c++, classes, struct

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
#ifndef PESSOA_H_INCLUDED
#define PESSOA_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

struct aniver{

    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
};

class Pessoa{

    private:

        std::string nome;
        std::string sexo;

        aniver nascimento;
        float altura;

    public:

        void setNome(std::string nome_);
        std::string getNome();
        void setSexo(std::string sexo_);
        std::string getSexo();
        void setNascimento(int dia, int mes, int ano);
        std::string getNascimento();
        void setAltura(float altura_);
        float getAltura();

    public:

        int calcIdade();

    public:

        void toString();

    };

#endif // PESSOA_H_INCLUDED
```

Sua implementação:

```
#include "Pessoa.h"
#include <ctime>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void Pessoa::setNome(std::string nome_){

     nome=nome_;
}

std::string Pessoa::getNome(){

     return nome;
}

void Pessoa::setSexo(std::string sexo_){

     sexo=sexo_;
}

std::string Pessoa::getSexo(){

     return sexo;
}

void Pessoa::setNascimento(int dia, int mes, int ano){

     nascimento.dia=dia;
     nascimento.mes=mes;
     nascimento.ano=ano;
}

std::string Pessoa::getNascimento(){

     std::ostringstream nascimento_str;

     nascimento_str << nascimento.dia << "-" << nascimento.mes << "-" << nascimento.ano;

     return nascimento_str.str();
}

void Pessoa::setAltura(float altura_){

     altura=altura_;
}

float Pessoa::getAltura(){

    return altura;
}

int Pessoa::calcIdade(){

    struct tm *birth;
    time_t now;

    double seconds;
    int years;

    time(&now);

    birth=localtime(&now);

    birth->tm_mday=nascimento.dia;
    birth->tm_mon=nascimento.mes;
    birth->tm_year=nascimento.ano-1900;

    seconds=difftime(now, mktime(birth));

    years=seconds/60/60/24/365;

    return years;
}

void Pessoa::toString(){

     std::cout << "Nome........: " << getNome() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Sexo........: " << getSexo() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Idade.......: " << calcIdade() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Peso........: " << getAltura() << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Nascimento..: " << getNascimento() << std::endl <<   std::endl;

}
```

Como já dito na pergunta eu gostaria de saber se é errado usar `struct` junto com `class` em c++ ou se a forma como apliquei `struct` no meu código foi desnecessária. Então, é errado o uso de `struct` junto com `class` em C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É totalmente normal e comum a criação de classes com campos do tipo estrutura.

```
struct Point2D {
    float x , y ;
} ;

class Transform {
    Point2D translation ;
    float xAxisRotationAngle ;
    float yAxisRotationAngle ;
    Point2D scaleFactors ;
    // ...
} ;
```

Esquisito foi a questão semântica envolvida. O tipo estrutura se chama `aniver` incluindo o ano, mas a data de aniversário de uma pessoa não tem um ano específico, todo ano tem aniversário. É melhor que a estrutura se chame `data` (assim desempenha o mesmo papel com ano incluso e ainda ganha um significado mais amplo, fazendo sentido seu uso não só em datas de nascimento e aniversário mas também outras datas) e o campo da classe seja uma data de nascimento.

Mais alguma dúvida?

Answer (score 2):

Em C++ classe e estrutura são a mesma coisa. A única diferença é que estrutura tem seus membros públicos por padrão e classe eles são privados por padrão. Se explicitar a visibilidade no código, não faz diferença usar uma ou outra. As pessoas escolhem usar uma ou outra por convenção, para indicar a forma como normalmente será usada, mas não é algo que a linguagem exige.

Então é normal usar tipos que sejam `struct` ou `class` dentro de uma `struct` ou `class`. De certa forma já faz isso. Um `int` é como se fosse uma `struct` muito simples, tão simples que nem precisa ser declarada assim, mas no fundo é a mesma coisa.

Na verdade tem uma série de outras coisas que são muito esquisitas no código. Funciona, mas ele não parece ser um código C++.

O maior problema, e aí é erro é que ele está corrompendo a memória por criar um ponteiro para a estrutura e não inicializá-lo. É verdade que provavelmente estes ponteiro não é necessário, se se uso precisa fazer tudo correto. Curiosamente talvez tenha outros membros que deveriam ser ponteiros (inteligentes). E depois existem outros problemas que farão o código se comportar errado.

Em qualquer linguagem a tentativa erro não funciona muito bem, mas elas dão um índice de acerto razoável quando compila. Em C++ não dá certo. O índice de acerto é baixo quando não se sabe profundamente o que está fazendo. É muito fácil funcionar e estar errado e o problema só aparecer muito tempo depois.

Portanto o problema da pergunta não existe, mas o código tem vários outros problemas.